# Does Civilization 5 have a mod including spies?

Tags: civilization-5, mods

I was wondering, are there mods which include a spy unit, as they appeared in older versions?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think we can help you with this request. We ruled recommendation questions to be out of scope of the site; this includes "is there such a thing as X?"

Comment: After discussion with badp and Grace Note, this question was determined not to be a game-rec question, and so it has been reopened.

Comment: (I still think this is a game-rec but I'm not going out of my way to super-close this again.)

Comment: Minor bump because I stumbled across this and hey, the Civ V expansion did add espionage.

Comment: Yeay!!! (i'm still wondering why it wasnt' there right from the beginning...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at the moment.  The mod tools are still somehwat limited since the source code for many of the libraries has not yet been released, so I don't think it is possible to create all the underlying systems of espionage points, missions, etc.  I wouldn't be surprised to see it in the future though.