# Civilization 5 great prophet mod?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

In the early game Great Prophets function nicely to create and enhance religions. However, later on, I find their effect on religion entirely overpowered. They can be used to convert *entire cities*, and the AI usually goes for my holy cities and those that benefit greatly from beliefs I have chosen specifically with those cities in mind. A city of millions of people in 1960s just drops the religion they've been following for a couple of thousand years and completely converts. So the question is, is there a mod for great prophets that prevents this from happening?

Comment: I would appreciate if all the people leaving minus votes could leave some feedback in a comment.

Comment: I have voted to close your question because recommendation questions don't work very well for Arqade. You're looking for a mod that essentially changes key game mechanics so the game plays more to your liking.  That's not really something we can help you with, I'm afraid.

Comment: I didn't vote one way or the other, but felt I should point out that [downvotes are anonymous.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/please-dont-misuse-the-voting-system?cb=1) There's no harm in asking, just don't always expect an answer.

Comment: Thanks for feedback @fbueckert. I didn't expect this to happen because I saw other people asking for mod recommendations with good results. For example, here is one asking if there is a mod for adding spies: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17145/does-civilization-5-have-a-mod-including-spies

Comment: Nice find there.  I've also voted to close that one.  Our rules have coelesced since that question was asked, and occasionally, old questions get missed.

Comment: @SMeznaric: You'd be welcome to ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) though.

Comment: I see. My bad, I should have read the rules better.

Comment: To be fair, the question asking about spies is fairly old, even to the point of being out dated now, as spies were implemented in the Gods & Kings expansion.

Comment: I solved the problem by modding the game myself. The mod is to eliminate Great Prophet's religion spreading capability. The only issue is I am not sure if the AI will respond appropriately to the new game rules. I will soon find out if there are impotent great prophets running around. If anyone else wants to give this a try, set religion spread ability to false in assets/DLC/Expansion/Gameplay/XML/Units/Civ5Units_Expansion.xml for the great prophet (the first unit in the file).

Comment: I appreciate the question... is there a mod for Civ5?  I would add that a good mod would be not to eliminate great prophet but use the  number of years of the former religion as some type of defense against conversion

Comment: If you find one Mike let us know.

Answer (score 2):

You don't strictly need a mod for this, it is possible to defend against a Great Prophet within the rules of the standard game.

As per a previous question of mine, [Can I politely stop an AI's Great Prophet from getting to my cities?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75065/can-i-politely-stop-an-ais-great-prophet-from-getting-to-my-cities), you can do one or both of the following:

- Station Inquisitors in your cities - they will prevent any Prophet or Missionary from acting in that city.
- Using non-combat units (such as workers) you can block the 'attacking' unit from getting next to your cities - a Prophet or Missionary has to be adjacent to your city to act.

If it's too late, and one of your cities has been converted, then Inquisitors can clear the 'attacking' religion, so you can then spread yours back to the city again (with Missionaries or time).

Comment: Yes, I read this post before I asked the question and I used this solution successfully a couple of times. The reason I asked is because I don't like to waste faith points on inquisitors just to station them in my cities.

Comment: That's similar to saying you don't want to waste time building soldiers, just so they can defend your cities - if you're not going to spend time/effort/money/resources/etc on defending yourself properly then you'll be leaving yourself open, and it shouldn't be a surprise when an opponent takes advantage of the weaknesses you leave exposed.

Comment: If I didn't want to do any of it then I wouldn't be playing Civ5. The reason this particular feature bothers me is that it completely destroys the immersion. I like to see religion evolve more organically and not for an AI to be able to just drop a religious atomic bomb in the middle of the map somewhere.